# How to Launch custom Powerapps Intake form from SharePoint Library-Not List

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp, powerapps-forms, sharepoint-library

I have a Document Library in SharePoint Online in which I customized the form with PowerApps.  I configured the app to function exactly how I want.  Leveraging Power Automate, I was able to create an Intake form that uploads a file and populates metadata on a button click from the app.  the problem is, I don't have anywhere for the users to actually Launch the app.  The one method I know I can do, but don't necessarily want to do, is add a PowerApps web part on the main page.  This works, but it's not how my customer wants this to work.  Is there any way I can launch this Library's PowerApps form from the +New button?  This is meant to function similarly to a List.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to open document library "properties" form directly using URL?

Comment: When a user navigates to the Library, I want them to use my PowerApps form to upload their file and populate the metadata.  When I run the app the process works (kicks off a workflow).  It creates a new entry in the Library complete with the File and the metadata (text and choice columns).  What I'd like is for them to click the +New button to directly launch the form.  I know we can do that with a List, just checking to see what my options are with a Library.

Comment: But yes to your question, that could work too.  Problem is, I don't have the Web Link available, because I'm working with a customized form from a Library

Comment: Did you create a standalone canvas app or customized document library "properties" form?

Comment: In case of customized properties form, form is available only when you select existing file/folder in library, correct?

Comment: It's a customized document library form.  And yes that appear to be correct.  I'm trying to use this form as a mechanism to upload the file and populate the metadata first.  I'm able to use the form in the PowerApps web part on the main page, which I don't really want to do...but might be my only option.